# Problemas com conexão à base de dados

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho um erro que não foi possível conectar à base de dados na linha 125 no ficheiro que eu vou deixar [aqui](http://ul.to/ecmzv6nf).

Pois entregaram-me um site para a mão mas não entendo nada do contigo que no ficheiro em cima vem.

Tenho que ligar (para testes) a host: localhost; username: root; database:saber;
e nao tem palavra-passe (não sei se estes dados são vos precisos mas vou meter na mesma)

Alguém me pode dizer o que dá erro?

PS: Eu sou muito novo na ligação **PHP** e **DB**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
host: localhost
```

Indica que o servidor SQL está no mesmo servidor que seu site. Então, se você está rodando um teste local na sua máquina, não irá encontrar o servidor. Garanta que o código esteja rodando no mesmo servidor do banco.

```
username:root
```

Estou imaginando que o banco seja o MySQL, onde o username padrão é root e sem senha (palavra-passe). Neste caso pode ser que alguem alterou ou criou a senha para o usuário root. Procure alguma ferramenta do tipo MySQL-Front que te permite conectar com o banco de dados para saber de realmente os dados de conexão estão OK.

Comment: eu fiz isso exactamente: (**var $username = 'root';** **var $password = '';** **var $hostname = 'localhost';** **var $database = 'saber';**), mas continua a dar erro